# Save .txt files with chromedriver instead of displaying it on browser

Tags: selenium, text, selenium-chromedriver

I have a project in which I have several .txt files urls. When I use driver.get(url)I get a window with the text content, I want to directly start downloading the text file instead. So far I am creating a text file and saving the text from driver.page_source but sometimes the text is big and the driver fails.

Is there a way to make chromedriver directly download text files instead of displaying them?

This is a sample code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/62450/62450-0.txt")
with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(driver.page_source)
```

Again what I am looking for is to directly download the text files (I can´t use requests module in my network).
It open the

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Comment: I have added a sample code :)

Answer (score 1):

See if this does what you are looking for. This strategy uses pyautogui to click Ctrl + S to save the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pyautogui

driver=webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://www.gutenberg.org/files/62450/62450-0.txt")
#with open("test.txt", "w") as file:
#    file.write(driver.page_source)

FILE_NAME = "TEST_FILE"
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 's')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.typewrite(FILE_NAME + '.txt')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.hotkey('enter')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have to do this for thousands of files some of them weight 20kb others 10mb, adding sleep seconds would the whole process last half a day more. Webdrivers´ get function already waits until the page is fully loaded so is not necessary to add sleep time, at most i put waits of 0.2 seconds and works like a charm.

I am looking for a way to set up the browser to directly downloaded text files instead of them being displayed. My example seems to be more efficient in time and lines of code.